# Exclude a column from Show-ListView in sitecore powershell

Tags: powershell-extensions, powershell

I have a list of object `$Results` which contains different  columns every time we run the script  according to user input but one column is fixed every time called `ItemID`

I am trying to display all columns present in `$Results` except `ItemID` using `Show-ListView`
but I am not able to find any command for this

Answer (score 1):

You can prepare a custom object and include the required property in the custom object. That way you can exclude other properties.

```
$item = Get-Item -Path "master:\content\home\sample item 1"
 
$Results = [pscustomobject]@{
    "Icon"=$Item.__Icon
    "DisplayName"=$Item.DisplayName
    "ItemPath"=$Item.ItemPath
    "Version"=$Item.Version
    "Language"=$Item.Language
}

$Results | Show-ListView
```

**Update:**

You can prepare a result object based on provided input value during execution. for e.g

```
$inputValue = Show-Input "Please provide value 1 or 2" 
Write-Host "The value you've provided is '$($inputValue)'"

if ($inputValue -eq "1")
  { 
    $item = Get-Item -Path "master:\content\home\sample item 1"
      
    $Results = [pscustomobject]@{
    "Icon"=$Item.__Icon
    "DisplayName"=$Item.DisplayName
    "ItemPath"=$Item.ItemPath
    "Version"=$Item.Version
    "Language"=$Item.Language
    }

    $Results | Show-ListView
      
  }
elseif ($inputValue -eq "2")
  { 
   $item = Get-Item -Path "master:\content\home\sample item 1"

   $Results = [pscustomobject]@{
    "Icon"=$Item.__Icon
    "DisplayName"=$Item.DisplayName
    "ItemPath"=$Item.ItemPath
   }

   $Results | Show-ListView
  }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: number of columns are not same every time it depends on the input provided during the execution

Comment: Updated my answer, you can use conditions and prepare objects based on provided value.